# Eclipse E4 - UIEvents Mpart Closure/Opening

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4

Does somebody know if there's a UIEvents which tracks the closure/opening of a MPart?

Just to remark it, I don't need a @PreDestroy method. I have some actions to perform outside the MPart's class.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `UIEvents` use the `EPartService` `IPartListener`:

```java
@Inject
EPartService partService;


partService.addPartListener(listener);
```

The `IPartListener` has methods called for all major changes to parts.

Note: This is `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.IPartListener` **not** `org.eclipse.ui.IPartListener`